# Powershell loop working but still returning error

Tags: loops, powershell

I have the following powershell script that renames a file with the current date after it has been moved to the destination folder:

```
##DateStamp

$DateStamp = get-date -uformat "%Y%m%d"

$files = @(get-childitem C:\PowershellTesting\FolderTwo\*.csv)

    foreach ($file in $files)    
{
 get-childitem | rename-item $file -NewName {"CompanyName" + $DateStamp + ".csv"}}
```

The script actually works in renaming the file, although it still gives me multipler iterations of this error:

```
rename-item : Cannot rename because item at 'C:\PowershellTesting\FolderTwo\17Feb17082308_CompanyName_20170217.csv' does not exist.
At line:11 char:18
```

I am guessing this is due to the loop not exiting once the file has been renamed, given that there is only one. Given that it works, I'm guessing I am missing something simple that will help me get rid of the error?

Comment: If I remove that get-ChildItem then it doesn't work at all and gives me this error:

Rename-Item : Cannot evaluate parameter 'NewName' because its argument is specified as a script block and there is no input. A script block cannot be evaluated without input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> get-childitem | rename-item $file -NewName {"CompanyName" + $DateStamp + ".csv"}}
> ```

Your working directory is what will be returned and passed to `Rename-Item` here for *each csv*.  Remove `Get-ChildItem` and just use rename item since you have the file object as `$file` anyway. This would be the smallest change to get what you want.

```
$file | rename-item -NewName {"CompanyName" + $DateStamp + ".csv"}}
```

I would caution your rename logic as every file will *attempt* to get the same name. If any are in the same directory you will get conflicts.

This can be shortened to the following. Keep in mind the above caveat still applies

```
$DateStamp = get-date -uformat "%Y%m%d"
Get-ChildItem "C:\PowershellTesting\FolderTwo\*.csv" | 
    Rename-Item  -NewName {"CompanyName" + $DateStamp + ".csv"}
```

Comment: Thanks - and I think the file will be deleted once it has been sent on, so there should only be one file in the folder when the script runs.